# Finding Max of different fields

Tags: linq-to-objects

```
Public class Inquiry
{
Public Date Inquirydate;
Public Date submittedDate;
Public Date VerifiedDate;
}

List<Inquiry> InquiryList= new List<Inquiries>();
```

Form this collection I need to get the latest of InquiryDate,submittedDate and verifiedDate.
Please note that the collection contains 5 objects and hence total 15 dates. Eeach object will have a latest date out of three fields and result should be the latest of all 15 dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little trick for that to easily select `Max` from that 3 dates within each object:

```
var maxDate = InquiryList.Max(i => (new DateTime[] { i.Inquirydate, i.submittedDate, i.VerifiedDate }).Max());
```

Or use `SelectMany`:

```
var = maxDate = InquiryList.SelectMany(i => new DateTime[] { i.Inquirydate, i.submittedDate, i.VerifiedDate }).Max();
```

Comment: @user2117804 You're welcome! However, You should upvote and/or mark answer as accepted if it solves your problem. That's how StackOverflow works!